# check from a list of li which one is display block and get its html

Tags: jquery

i am trying to get html from the the list of li finding which one is display block and get that li's html. all i want is to get the html from the display:block li out of four li

```
 if ($('.fishes li').is(':visible'))
 {
 var price=$(this).find('span').html();
 alert(price);
 }
```

but using this is not getting the value i want . its not taking out html from the display:block li . the click source is different.

the click source is `$(document).on("click", ".test", function()`

Comment: `$('.fishes li:visible').html()` ?

Answer (score 0):

In your posted code, `$(this)` is referring to the `.test` element. Try this instead:

```
$(document).on("click", ".test", function() { 
    console.log($('.fishes li:visible').find('span').html());
});
```

Comment: its giving out the value of the first li only even if the second one is displa:block

Answer (score 0):

by using this `$(".fishes li:not(.hidn)").find("span:first").html();` worked for me sharing it out for some one in help thanks